# How to copy a file to all subdirectories?

Tags: linux, shell, find, cp

How can I paste `read-me.jpg` file into all sub-directories? Here is a command to create a new file in all subdirectories.

```
for dir in `find . -type d` ; do echo "mywebsite.com" > $dir/downloadedfrom.txt ; done
```

But I want to copy `jpg` file into all subdirectories instead.

**Directory List:**

```
2011
2012
2009
2019
2021
2000/2001/..../2010
...
...
```

already tried with this command but no output

```
for dir in `find . -type d` ; cp read-me.jpg > $dir ; done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tried to redirect `cp`'s output into `$dir` but instead we should specify the destination `$dir/read-me.jpg` as the second argument of `cp`

```
for dir in `find . -type d` ; do cp read-me.jpg $dir/read-me.jpg ; done
```

Answer (score 5):

`cp` and `>` don't mix. `cp`'s syntax is `cp source destination` with no redirections.

When possible use `find -exec` to execute a command on each result. It's simpler and less error prone than looping over its output.

```
find . -type d -exec cp read-me.jpg {} ';'
```

When using `-exec`, `{}` is a placeholder for the paths that are found, and `';'` is a required piece of syntax to signal the end of the `-exec` action (in case there are additional `find` options following the `-exec`).